# on Calling External API in NodeJS I am getting below error

Tags: node.js

```
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// const request = require('request');
const app = express();
const lib = require('lib');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const port = 3009
var username = 'abc.brodi@sixteendrops.org';
var password = 'abc.brodi@sixteenrops.org';
app.post('/', (err, req, res) => {
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://apimatic.io/api/transform?format=openapi',
    auth: {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
        'Authorization': 'Basic a2F3c2FyLmJyb2RpQHNpeGRyb3BzLvZGlAc2l4ZHJvcHMub3Jn',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': 'ARRAffinity=151dd97860ff62b41c849012ff97; ARRAffinity=31fe78b60cd3475555aefb722fea9e6225bba3d491724d5ca88424ffcffa3908; ARRAffinitySameSite=31fe78b60cd3475555aefb722fea9e6225bba3d491724d5ca88424ffcffa3908',
      },
}
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    const promise = controller.transformViaFile(inputtedFile, ExportFormats);
    data = JSON.stringify(ExportFormats)
    res.json({
        data: data
    }).catch(err =>{
        res.statuscode = 422,
        res.json({
            data:null,
            error:true
        })

    })
})
})
app.listen(3009, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
```

ON sending Request with Postman I am getting an error post method not allowed, I am calling an Above API with Nodejs express server I am sending request with postman. could you please help me to get that.

With the postman I want to upload a file and I want to add params, with AUth username and password

[image]

Comment: You are getting this error because not route configured for `localhost:3009` though we can see you have route POST /abc in your code. Are you not suppose to call route `/abc`?

Comment: I tried by removing the abc from the POST route i am getting the same error